# Access to textview from threads

Tags: android

I have an activity with a textview, created from the layout.xml.
Inside this activity I created a thread.
I want want to use my textview from inside the thread but each time I do something like textview.setText() my program forces to close.

The question is : why I cannot access to textview from the thread ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is You are trying to interfere in Ui Thread from a non UI thread so in order to do such things from non ui- thread

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {            
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            // Add your GUI code here  like setText from your perspective              
        }
    });
```

Comment: Or you can use Handler object or AsyncTask instead of Thread.

Comment: It works fine, thank you. Much less complicated than reading the Handler and AsyncTask theory :-(

Comment: if your problem is solved then mark it accepted by clicking the left hand correct aarow this way you improve your chance of getting good answers